# Can one solana keypair have multiple addresses?

Tags: validator, keypair, address

I am trying to build an exchange which would work in a such a way that the funds are stored in an address for certain limit and once that limit is crossed, the address is changed but the signer for the accounts is not changed. Is this possible? If not, what are the other possible ways we can implement similar ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a BIP39 mnemonic you can derive as many accounts from it as necessary. So one backup that can derive account keypairs to compartementalize risk.

https://www.ledger.com/academy/crypto/what-are-hierarchical-deterministic-hd-wallets

See this answer https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/1032/1128 for more technical details as to how to generate account keypairs from the mnemonic