# Import a Base58 private key into Solana cli

Tags: solana-cli, private-key

I have the following example private key:

4YFq9y5f5hi77Bq8kDCE6VgqoAqKGSQN87yW9YeGybpNfqKUG4WxnwhboHGUeXjY7g8262mhL1kCCM9yy8uGvdj7

It's paired with the address:

B7EZQq7AV8FnEEvEZUiFDPbfUWNE12XZv6wvn9ubFUJV

How do I import this key into Solana cli without having to install a bunch of other libraries or tools?

Comment: Most of the CLI that need a keypair (private and public) take a filepath to keyfile as option

Comment: can i just copy that private key into a file and it still works?

Comment: May I ask what the use case of needing to pass the base-58 version into the CLI? The JSON-string version (the 32 number JSON array) is alot of characters, but it works with `stdin` for feeding keypairs into the solana CLI.

Comment: @HelmetFace I have a service where I save the base-58 private keys of my users and when the users process a send transaction I have a script that is suppose to take that as an input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Solana CLI, it is possible to pass a keypair in from stdin *without writing it to a file first*.

This can be demonstrated using any keypair file and doing:

```
$ cat my-keypair.json | solana --keypair stdin:// address
<your-address-will-appear-here>
```

As you can see, it just expects a byte-array, one that is identical to the contents of a typical keypair file, not a Base58 string.

Now, if I understand you correctly, you have some program that calls the Solana CLI as a subprocess, and you want to pass in the private key. As per the above, you can convert your Base58 representation of your private key into a JSON string of a byte array (e.g. `[234, 10, 56, 42 ...]`, and then you can pass that string into stdin of your subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

Are you comfortable with command line, node, and npm? If so, the snippet below will output the file that you can use for Solana CLI.

May sound like a lot, but I just went through this with a non-dev friend and they succeeded.

**STEPS:**

1. In your command line, type `node -v` does this say something like `v16.17.0` ? If not, you can [install node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).
2. Then, create a new directory with a JS file... named `convert.js` for example and copy the code below into it. Don't forget to update the `privatekeyexportedfromphantom` value.
3. You can then type `npm i bs58` from the command-line in that directory. (installs bs58)
4. Finally, type `node convert.js` and it will create a file named `mykey.json`

**CODE:**

```
const bs58 = require('bs58');
const fs = require('fs');
b = bs58.decode('privatekeyexportedfromphantom');
j = new Uint8Array(b.buffer, b.byteOffset, b.byteLength / Uint8Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
fs.writeFileSync('mykey.json', `[${j}]`);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment and your follow up question:

- Many of the commands to the `solana` CLI take a keypair file as an
  argument
- The keypair  file is an array of bytes written out as a json
  array.
- Decode the string from base58 into an array then use a json
  writer to put to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small Python script that converts private key into byte array. It is fairly simple and it has come in handy many times.

```
 python3 -m pip install base58
```

If you are using python3, first install base58 using the command above. You need pip to install this package.

```
import base58
byte_array = base58.b58decode('4YFq9y5f5hi77Bq8kDCE6VgqoAqKGSQN87yW9YeGybpNfqKUG4WxnwhboHGUeXjY7g8262mhL1kCCM9yy8uGvdj7')

json_string = "[" + ",".join(map(lambda b: str(b), byte_array)) + "]"
print(json_string)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Getting errors: https://prnt.sc/28SOZBeHwJHi --- " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base58' "

Comment: if you are using python3, please use this to install it first before you can import.

python3 -m pip install base58