# python find_program_address, how to covert a pubkey to a byte array as in rust?

Tags: pda, python

this is a really simple question but I can't seem to find an example to do it.  In a rust client I am just doing the following:

```
let (user_data_account, _user_bump_seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[&user_id.to_le_bytes()], &program);
let (user_id_map, _user_id_map_bump_seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[&user_account.to_bytes()], &program);
```

where user_account is a PubKey, and user_id is a u64.

In python, I am trying to use https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/ but PubKey doesn't have a to_bytes method, and i'm not really sure what to do to be able to get the same program address as I would get from the rust code (the same goes for the U64 really..)

Anyone done this before?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have previously answered this question here - https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/2739/486

```
import base58
byte_array = base58.b58decode('4YFq9y5f5hi77Bq8kDCE6VgqoAqKGSQN87yW9YeGybpNfqKUG4WxnwhboHGUeXjY7g8262mhL1kCCM9yy8uGvdj7')
json_string = "[" + ",".join(map(lambda b: str(b), byte_array)) + "]"
print(json_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

`PublicKey` does have what you're looking for: `bytes(key)`